# Postfix: multiple recipients and separate transport (FILTER) per recipient

Tags: postfix

I have set up a default smart host/relay for all external mail as follows:

main.cf:

```
relayhost = [1.2.3.4]:587
```

However, I want recipients with specific MX (n.b. *google.com) to be sent directly, without using the relayhost, so I did:

main.cf:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  check_recipient_mx_access pcre:/etc/postfix/mxtransport
  ...
```

mxtransport:

```
/google\.com$/ FILTER smtp:
/googlemail\.com$/i FILTER smtp:
```

This is working as it should for a single recipient. If mail is addressed to multiple recipients (using To:/Cc:/Bcc:) and some of the specified recipients satisfy the mxtransport rule and some do not, Postfix sends mail to ALL recipients ignoring the default relayhost definition.  For example, if I send email to joe.doe@gmail.com, Postfix correctly sets the filter and sends mail directly without using smarthost.  However, if I send mail to multiple recipients containing joe.doe@outlook.com, joe.doe@gmail.com, it would still assume I want to skip smarthost for ALL recipients.

Is it possible to have different transport per recipient when multiple recipients are specified?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible, because `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` is evaluated while the message is being received, so only one result can apply to the entire message.  Normally you'd use transport maps for this, but that can only lookup based on the recipient domain, not on the recipient domain's MX records.

Comment: Well, it's a pity and seems like incorrect implementation on the Postfix side.  IMHO, it should apply rules in smtpd_recipient_restrictions per recipient (for cases when mail is addressed to multiple recipients), and remember the FILTER applied via check_recipient_mx_access per recipient as well.

Comment: I'm sure a PR would be considered.  Note, however, that the primary purpose of `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` is to accept/reject a message, and SMTP has no way to selectively reject a single recipient from a delivery attempt -- fail one recipient, the whole SMTP delivery attempt fails.